# Why does vsnprintf cause format string vulnerability

Tags: c, security, string-formatting

I have the following code and am trying to understand why vsnprintf will cause a format string vulnerability.

If I execute the program as follows "./test %llx" Is the vulnerability caused because "%llx" has been passed into va_list and is then interpreted by vsprintf and thus causing the format string vuln?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 512

void cmd(char *dir)
{
    char errbuf[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
    snprintf(errbuf, 512, "Error '%s'.\n", dir);
    puts("cmd: ");
    puts(errbuf);
    control_printf(2, errbuf);
}

void control_printf(char success, char *format, ...)
{
    char buffer[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    va_list val;
    va_start(val, format);
    puts("control_printf before vsnprintf: ");
    puts(format);
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, val);
    va_end(val);
    puts("control_printf after vsnprintf: ");
    puts(buffer);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\r\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    cmd(argc[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

How could I resolve the issue?

Comment: Why the magic number 2 in `control_printf(2, errbuf);`? Did you try this: `snprintf(errbuf, 512, "Error \"%s\".\n", dir);`?

Comment: The "2" will be used as a parameter elsewhere in that function, haven't come up with that yet.

Comment: Where do you see an error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get, what you are trying to accomplish here, but the vulnerability comes from letting the <s>user</s>hacker supply a format string. He can then supply `%n` which causes the `printf`-function-family to write to memory (the number of bytes written so far).

```
int answer = 42;
printf("Hello %nworld\n", &answer);
// "Hello " is 6 bytes long
printf(
    "The answer to the ultimate question of life, "
    "the universe and everything is: %i\n"
    , answer
);
```

Will print 6 as answer, instead of 42.